# How to remove dotted outline a link in QTextBrowser?

Tags: qt, qtextbrowser

I used `QTextCharFormat` to format a link style and insert into a `QTextBrowser`, when click this link, it show dotted outline (I thought this is its focus style). How to remove these dots when it's clicked?

Answer (score 2):

**Option A**

If you don't want the `QTextBrowser` to gain focus at all, the simplest possible one-liner solution is to set its [`focusPolicy`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusPolicy-prop):

```
textBrowser->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
```

Notice that this is somewhat brutal approach, though, and prevents keyboard navigation altogether. In that respect, setting the focus policy to `Qt::TabFocus` is much nicer, but it won't prevent the focus rectangle to appear when `QTextBrowser` does have focus.

**Option B**

An alternative approach is to use a custom, or rather proxy, style to change the appearance of the focus indicator.

```
#include <QProxyStyle>

class MyProxyStyle : public QProxyStyle
{
public:
    int styleHint(StyleHint hint, const QStyleOption *option, const QWidget *widget, QStyleHintReturn *returnData) const
    {
        if (hint == SH_TextControl_FocusIndicatorTextCharFormat)
            return false;
        return QProxyStyle::styleHint(hint, option, widget, returnData);
    }
};
```

and then:

```
textBrowser->setStyle(new MyProxyStyle);
```

If you're interested in the implementation details to see how it works under the hood, see [QWidgetTextControl::getPaintContext()](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qwidgettextcontrol.cpp#n3206) and [QCommonStyle::styleHint()](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/styles/qcommonstyle.cpp#n5140). In short, the desired appearance is queried from the style, which can set the desired text format in the return data.